# Error coming in running windows application on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

My windows application is created in .net framework 4.0 . I have deployed it on XP and Windows 7. It is running fine there but When I installed it on windows server 2008 R2 then after running application gives error like "**Common Language Runtime detected an Invalid Program**".

Please help if anyone has any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109179/invalidprogramexception-common-language-runtime-detected-an-invalid-program

Comment: Thanks I have already looked this but I don't have any primary key as decimal. Can you tell me what can be other issue.